# DRF create method in viewset or in serializer

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, serialization

What is the difference between customizing the "create" method in DRF viewset or customizing it in the serializer? I understand the serializer is responsible to deserialize the data, i.e. the way the data is presented in the POST query; however, I can also create objects in related fields in the serializer.

```
#views.py
def create(self, request):
    pass

#serializer.py
def create(self, validated_data):
    return Model.objects.create(**validated_data)
```

When should I customize views/create vs. serializer/create?

Comment: I like the viewset myself just for the fact that request object (if needed) is already there and i dont need to write extra code to pass extra args to the serializer. I also like to separate both logics from each other, so create on viewset level is for requests that are meant to actually create a record on backend, while the create on serializer level is to create an object from serialized and return for you do what you need with it.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

### `create` method from viewset

This method handles the `POST` request logic in the view, which by default does:

- instantiate the serializer with whatever data comes as payload in the request
- executed the `is_valid` method on the serializer
- perform the actual create by calling `.save()` method on serializer
- returns the view `Response` with serialized data and 201 status

You don't really need to override the `create` method on viewset, if is something that you need to send to the serializer from the view itself you can override `perform_create` which by default does `serializer.save()`. Eg. if you want to send the user from the request you can do:

```
    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        # here you will send `created_by` in the `validated_data` 
        serializer.save(created_by=self.request.user)
```

Note: Behind the scene `save` method will execute the `create` method on serializer with the `validated_data`

### `create` method from serializer

This method just creates the actual model instance using the `validated_data`. You may override this method in case you need to create related objects, like the following:

```
   def create(self, validated_data):
        items_data = validated_data.pop('items')

        # similar to Parent.objects.create(**validated_data)
        parent = super().create(**validated_data)

        for item_data in items_data:
            Item.objects.create(parent=parent, **item_data)
        return parent
```

So here you are sending a payload with data regarding the `Parent` object but also a list of `items` with their representation, so now the `create` method will create also the Items and link them with the Parent instance.

To summarize this:

- in viewset the create method handles request-response flow
- in serializer the create method handles model instance creation using validated data.

Comment: How can I return a custom message like "created successfully" in this?

Comment: Why do you need that message? The view itself returns an http response with status code 201 if created successfully, you can use that.