# Django rest framework nested serializers partial updating

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have this nested serializer models.

```
class ApplicantSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
  
    work_experience = WorkExperienceSerializer(many=True, required=False)
    class Meta:
        model = Applicant
        fields = 'id','auid','completed','work_experience', 'insert_date','last_update'
        read_only_fields = ('id','insert_date', 'last_update')

    def create(self, validated_data):
        print('############################3creating data######################3')
        print(validated_data)
        work_experience = validated_data.pop('work_experience')
        applicant = Applicant.objects.create(**validated_data)

        for i in range(len(work_experience)):
            WorkExperience.objects.create(
                applicant=applicant, **work_experience[i]
            )
        return applicant
```

this is my output data of nested models when I create some of data

```
[
    {
        "id": 46,
        "auid": "5fd2c6e2-7eaa-472e-b4b1-beb23e3e5072",
        "completed": false,
        "work_experience": [
            {
                "id": 36,
                "from_date": "2020-11-23",
                "to_date": "2020-11-25",
                "event_type": "self-employment",
                "employer_name": null,
                "employment_type": null,
                "self_employment_name": null,
                "position": null,
                "business_activity": null,
                "profession": null,
                "job_title": null,
                "position_level": null,
                "roles_and_responsibilities": null,
                "top_achievement_1": null,
                "top_achievement_2": null,
                "top_achievement_3": null,
                "reason_for_change": null,
                "reason_for_leaving": null,
                "company_name": null,
                "address_line_1": null,
                "address_line_2": null,
                "address_line_3": null,
                "postcode": null,
                "city": null,
                "county": null,
                "country": null,
                "insert_date": "2020-11-26T20:18:36.277720Z",
                "last_update": "2020-11-26T20:18:36.277720Z"
            }
        ],
        "insert_date": "2020-11-26T20:18:36.209758Z",
        "last_update": "2020-11-26T20:18:36.209758Z"
    }
]
```

I have two models and using ForiegnKey for nested to them. In first time in the **ApplicantSerializer** Iam just creating part of data and for that data I want to do update as partial update an exist empty field.
and data Iam sending is work_experience.

**1**.so using this serialazer or views how I shall do the the parial update through the **Applicant** to the nested model of work_experience?

**2**. What's the difference between doing the update in the **Serializer** or in the **Views**?

Answer (score 0):

1. [DRF Writable Nested](https://github.com/beda-software/drf-writable-nested) may be the solution you're looking for. Or you may implement by yourself in `ApplicantSerializer.update`, by checking `id` of `work_experience`, you could decide to insert a new record or update an existing one.
2. For the 2nd question, you may refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63631030/5984193):

> **To summarize this:**
>
> - in viewset the create method handles request-response flow
> - in serializer the create method handles model instance creation using validated data.