# Django serializer returns empty dictionary on create

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have this model that basically joins two different users:

```
class Couple(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(
        primary_key=True,
        default=uuid.uuid4,
        editable=False)

    user1 = models.ForeignKey(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        null=True,
        blank=False,
        related_name="user1"
    )

    user2 = models.ForeignKey(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        null=True,
        blank=False,
        related_name="user2"
    )

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.id)
```

What I did next, was create a Serializer where user1 invites user2 to create a couple. And I want to do this by writing user2 email address:

```
class CreateCoupleSerializer(serializers.Serializer):

    partner_email = serializers.EmailField(write_only=True, max_length=250,
                                           required=True)

    def create(self, validated_data):
        partner_email = validated_data['partner_email']
        try:
            partner = User.objects.get(email=partner_email)
        except Exception:
            partner = None

        if not partner:
            raise serializers.ValidationError(
                {"details": 'User does not exist'})

        if partner.couple_id:
            raise serializers.ValidationError(
                {"details": 'User is already assigned to a couple'})

        user = self.context['request'].user
        couple = Couple.objects.create(user1=user, user2=partner)

        user.couple_id = couple.id
        partner.couple_id = couple.id
        user.save()
        partner.save()

        return couple
```

And this is my view:

```
class CreateCoupleView(generics.CreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = CreateCoupleSerializer
    queryset = Couple.objects.all()
```

By testing this I can see that the Couple is being created, which is great! However, in my body response, I'm getting an empty dictionary instead of the new couple instance.

[image]

**My question** is why is this happening?

**Bonus question:** When should I create logic in def create() from the Serializer side vs def create() on the View side?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Might be caused by that `write_only`, try removing it and see if serializer returns partner_email. On the second question https://stackoverflow.com/a/63631030/874027

Comment: Also, in case you have a custom User model, this kind of relationship would not require a m2m model, a simple foreign key would work fine. In custom User model. `couple = models.ForeignKey('self', null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)`

Comment: Side note: you are creating a "many to many" relationship here. Django gives us  `ManyToManyRelationship` that can minimize the code we write. With this, you add a `partners` field to your `User` class without the `Couple` model. Django will generate a table for you that is basically exactly like your explicit `Couple`.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice, that's true! My idea is not to have just 2 users in this Couple Model. I also want to add other fields for settings. In this case do you think makes sense to have this Couple model?

Comment: @MárioPrada Gotchya. Then yes, you probably have to create the `Couple` model to define this metadata on the relationship. You can still use a `ManyToManyRelationship` on the `User` model with a `through` parameter or the `ForeignKey`s like you currently have. I recommend googling "django many to many relationship" to find the official documentation and read more about it.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this by replacing it with `serializers.ModelSerializer` and defining `read_only_fields` like this:

```
class CreateCoupleSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

partner_email = serializers.EmailField(write_only=True, max_length=250,
                                       required=True)

class Meta:
    model = Couple
    fields = '__all__'
    read_only_fields = ('user1', 'user2', )
```